# Image uploaded to S3 becomes corrupted

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I’m having issues uploading a file from postman to aws lambda + s3. If I understand correctly the image has to be a base64 string and send via JSON to work with lambda and API Gateway so I converted an image to a base64 and I’m using the base64 string in postman

[image]

The file uploads to S3, but when I download the s3 object and open it I get

[image]

So I don’t think I’m uploading it correctly. I’ve used a base64 to image converter and the image appears so the base64 string is correct before sending it via postman so something in my setup is off. What am I doing wrong? I appreciate the help!

upload.js

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const s3 = new AWS.S3();
exports.handler = async (event, context, callback) => {
    let data = JSON.parse(event.body);
    let file = data.base64String;


    const s3Bucket = "upload-test3000";
    const objectName = "helloworld.jpg";
    const objectData = data.base64String;
    const objectType = "image/jpg";
    try {
        const params = {
            Bucket: s3Bucket,
            Key: objectName,
            Body: objectData,
            ContentType: objectType
        };
        const result = await s3.putObject(params).promise();
        return sendRes(200, `File uploaded successfully at https:/` + s3Bucket + `.s3.amazonaws.com/` + objectName);

    } catch (error) {
        return sendRes(404, error);
    }
};
const sendRes = (status, body) => {
    var response = {
        statusCode: status,
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Content-Type,X-Amz-Date,Authorization,X-Api-Key,X-Amz-Security-Token",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "OPTIONS,POST,PUT",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": true,
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
            "X-Requested-With": "*"
        },
        body: body
    };
    return response;
};
```

.png

Comment: Can you post the base64 encoded string within a gist or pastebin? So we can double check it's valid.

Comment: Here's the base64 string I'm using https://pastebin.com/b2A55Lh3

Comment: Unforunately, it says that paste is no longer available :(

Comment: Yea pastebin was deleting it. Here's a difference source: https://0bin.net/paste/z0zslIdN#E9XxfpS-KlQaVRmPbLx2ZIz2nQH/9utxJKXjv2k7Sr1

Comment: Decode your base64 string back to a jpeg before calling `s3.putObject`. Then the object written to S3 will be a valid binary jpg file instead of a base64 string containing a jpg. If you download `helloworld.jpg` from s3 i assume its base64 text not binary?

Comment: @MisterSmith I changed my code to now accept the JSON data of the base64 and then I decode it and upload it, but I'm getting the same unsupported file format error. Here's the updated code: https://pastebin.com/ir81STXK  Here is the s3 object meta info after performing upload: ```{'AcceptRanges': 'bytes', 'LastModified': '2020-12-03T19: 11: 29.000Z', 'ContentLength': 37762, 'ETag': '"bde7aa76f1da39635484c41190eb89f5"', 'ContentType': 'image/jpg', 'Metadata': {}
}```  Do you know what the issue is?

Comment: If I rewrite the function to be simply to return the decoded base64 string: https://pastebin.com/1QDPbGZk then it returns https://postimg.cc/ct1VNVj7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working by adding the base64 string in JSON format like so

[image]

and then sent

`let decodedImage = Buffer.from(encodedImage, 'base64');` as the `Body` param.

updated upload.js

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var s3 = new AWS.S3();


exports.handler = async (event) => {

    let encodedImage = JSON.parse(event.body).base64Data;
    let decodedImage = Buffer.from(encodedImage, 'base64');
    var filePath = "user-data/" + event.queryStringParameters.username + ".jpg"
    var params = {
        "Body": decodedImage,
        "Bucket": process.env.UploadBucket,
        "Key": filePath
    };

    try {
        let uploadOutput = await s3.upload(params).promise();
        let response = {
            "statusCode": 200,
            "body": JSON.stringify(uploadOutput),
            "isBase64Encoded": false
        };
        return response;
    }
    catch (err) {
        let response = {
            "statusCode": 500,
            "body": JSON.stringify(eerr),
            "isBase64Encoded": false
        };
        return response;
    }

};
```

I found this [article](https://medium.com/think-serverless/image-upload-and-retrieval-from-s3-using-aws-api-gateway-and-lambda-b4c2961e8d1) to be super helpful

Comment: The article you referenced was very helpful for me as well. thank you!

Answer (score 4):

When building the params you should add content encoding, otherwise you're just uploading the text data:

```
const params = {
  Bucket: s3Bucket,
  Key: objectName,
  Body: objectData,
  ContentType: objectType,
  ContentEncoding: 'base64'
};
```

**edit**

Okay I have checked the file, I think you might be misunderstanding what will happen when you store the image in base64.

Windows or a browser for that matter can't read a jpg file in base64 (as far as I know), it must be converted first. When you have an image in the browser with a base64 source, the browser handles this conversion on the fly but the base64 data inside the "helloworld.jpg" container is useless in windows without converting it.

There's two options, either convert once it reaches your server then upload directly as utf8 or have a layer in between, converting the image as it's requested.

Comment: I added ```ContentEncoding: 'base64'``` to the params, but I'm having the same issue. I download the object and I get unsupported format error when trying to open jpg. Any ideas?

Comment: If you download the file and open in a text editor, does it just display the same base64 string that you uploaded?

Comment: Yes I used a diffchecker and it's the exact same

Comment: This is the problem, the encoding doesn't seem to be applying to the file, so you have base64 data stored in standard encoding (probably utf8). If you check the metadata for the file in AWS does it show a `Content Encoding` value?

Comment: Here's the metadata of the s3 object ```{'AcceptRanges': 'bytes', 'LastModified': '2020-12-03T15: 23: 14.000Z', 'ContentLength': 27496, 'ETag': '"56cd10223bb062f921628bc62d6d2c6a"', 'ContentEncoding': 'base64', 'ContentType': 'image/jpg', 'Metadata': {}
}```

Comment: @user6680 I have added an update to my post

Comment: Whenever I try and upload the file via postman to my lambda function in SAM I get ```"POST /upload-file HTTP/1.1" 502``` I read somewhere that I needed to send the file in the BODY, but maybe I misunderstood making it base64 string inside JSON. I'm now uploading the jpg file using form-data in postman: https://postimg.cc/1nLhQn9P but I get the 502. Do you why I'm getting 502? Example code for file upload: https://pastebin.com/HJBCsswN If the function was empty and was set to return 200, then it would still get 502 so the file from postman isn't making it to the function

Comment: Is there a reason that you need to use base64? are you just uploading the image file to s3 from a file dialog?

Comment: I'm using Postman. I'm just trying to understand how to upload an image using aws lambda. If it doesn't need to use base64 to work then it's not a deal breaker. This is more for a learning experience.

Comment: @user6680 You could switch to using an enctype of `multipart/form-data` but you'd need to use a different processor like [multer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer) to handle the file

Answer (score 2):

The problem might be the passing format of image in Body, as it is not getting passed as expected by s3.upload parameters (It says Body key must be Buffer to be passed).

**So, The simple solution is pass the Body as buffer, if your file is** **present in any location in the directory then don't pass it like**

> ```
> // Wrong Way 
>
> const params = {
>    Bucket: 'Your-Buket-Name',
>    Key: 'abc.png', // destFileName i.e the name of file to be saved in s3 bucket
>    Body: 'Path-To-File'
> }
> ```

**Now, the problem is the file gets uploaded as Raw Text, which is corrupted format and will not be readable by the OS on downloading.**

So, to get it working pass it like

> ```
> // Correct Way According to aws-sdk library
>
> const fs = require('fs'); 
> const imageData = fs.readFileSync('Path-To-File'); // returns buffer
> const params = {
>    Bucket: 'Your-Buket-Name',
>    Key: 'abc.png', // destFileName i.e the name of file to be saved in s3 bucket
>    Body: imageData // image buffer
> }
> const uploadedFile = await s3.upload(params).promise();
> ```

**Note: During answer i was using -> "aws-sdk": "^2.1025.0"**

Hope this will help you or somebody else. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**This is occur due to inappropriate UPLOAD of file.**

The best way to solve this problem is to use standard methods. Means use XMLHttpRequest in place of axios , and use BLOB of file which we fetch from the URL.

this is the method which is work for me. I hope this is also helpful to you.

```
const uploadFile = async (fileObject) => {

function uriToBlob(uri) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.onload = function () {
            resolve(xhr.response);
        };
        xhr.onerror = function () {
            reject(new Error('uriToBlob failed'));
        };
        xhr.responseType = 'blob';
        xhr.open('GET', uri, true);
        xhr.send(null);
    });
}

try {
    const res = await axios.get(`${baseURL}/uploadUrl`, {
        params: {
            contentType: fileObject.photoObject.type,
            type: fileObject.type
        }
    })

    const { url } = res.data;

    // console.log(fileObject.photoObject);

    const file = await uriToBlob(fileObject.photoObject.uri);

    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('PUT', url);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
            if (xhr.status === 200) {
                console.log("uploded");
            } else {
                alert("Enable to upload the image! please try again.")
            }
        }
    };
    xhr.send(file);

    return { imageName: res.data.imageName };
}
catch (err) {
    alert("Enable to upload the image! please try again.");
    return;
}}
```